# How to (Re)-Install Npm

Tags: node.js, npm

When trying to install `npm` (which my package manager says is not installed) I get this:

```
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/doc:
       cpio: rename
```

When pretending I have it and trying to install modules I get this:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../lib/npm.js'
```

How do I install/reinstall npm?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Double check that `npm` is uninstalled:

```
# dnf remove npm
```

(I'm using Fedora but do the above with whatever package manager you use)

Now remove the remants:

```
# rm -rf /usr/lib/node_modules/npm
# rm /usr/bin/npm
```

Credit: http://whirlwin.blogspot.com/2013/07/npm-update-error-in-linux.html